# How to add entry having to lookup foreign key ID

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have multiple locations defined in my DB.  For example purposes, say I have "Mimai" as a city.  I am trying to understand how I add a **Measurment** entry and reference the **Location ID** for the city "Miami" in Location.  Each **Location** will have many **Measurements**.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(('city'), max_length=20)
    geolocation = models.PointField(('location'))

class Measurement(models.Model):
    server      = models.CharField(('server'), max_length=10)
    cpu_util    = models.CharField(('cpu'), max_length=10)
    date        = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    location    = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Question #1** Would I do?

```
m = Measurement.objects.update_or_create(
    server      = "Bubba",
    cpu_util    = "100%",
    location    = Location.objects.get(city="Miami")
)
```

Or (if this is possible?)

```
l = Location.objects.get(city="Miami")
m = Measurement.objects.update_or_create(
    server      = "Bubba",
    cpu_util    = "100%",
    location    = l.id
)
```

**Question #2**  There should only be 1 **Measurement** per day for each **Location**.  In the event a **Measurement** is added twice with the same date, I take update_or_create would update **cpu_util** if the value was different?

Comment: while storing a foreign key you have to pass whole object so pass the `location` object inside the `measurement` table

Comment: @AbiWaqas, sorry but I am not following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**:  Both work (notice the change)

```
m = Measurement.objects.update_or_create(
    server      = "Bubba",
    cpu_util    = "100%",
    location    = Location.objects.get(city="Miami")
)
Or (if this is possible?)

l = Location.objects.get(city="Miami")
m = Measurement.objects.update_or_create(
    server      = "Bubba",
    cpu_util    = "100%",
    location    = l
)
```

**Question 2**: Add unique_together to your model

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    server      = models.CharField(('server'), max_length=10)
    cpu_util    = models.CharField(('cpu'), max_length=10)
    date        = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    location    = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('location','date')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think the unique_together is giving me issues.  I am experiencing "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "measurements_measurement_location_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (location_id)=(47) already exists."

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to add a second measurement for the same location:day pair